# jQuery - Windows + Mac Hotkeys / Targetting those keys

Tags: jquery, windows, macos, ascii, accessibility

I've been doing a bit of exploring on the net and I've failed to find an example to use.

I'm trying to add accessibility into my site, I've currently got Windows hotkey's working, however I do not know how to do the mac keys.
I don't know the codes.

This is the working code.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.altKey) {
        if (e.which == 49) {window.location.replace("URL")};
});
```

If I could get an example of something like for windows:

```
if (e.ctrlKey + altKey) { if (e.which == Key#) {Do something};
```

In simple English. Press Ctrl + Alt + Key = Trigger Code

And an example or a source to find out how do to Mac

Press Control + Option + Key = Trigger Code

Also, if anyone knows a site similar to http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ That shows the Mac keyboard numbers that would be amazing. I had a look for them, but many references I checked show different numbers. Anyone have an official source?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y98s0yg4/1/

Comment: Thank you @ArunPJohny That helps solve the Windows accessibility issue I was having. Do you know the Mac version of Control + Option + Key?

Comment: You may be able to side-step some of the browser/platform compat by using the accesskey attribute on a link element - eg. `<a href=... accesskey='1'>`. The browser will then handle the keyboard logic for you - downside is that different browsers will use different modifiers - but at least you'll be consistent with that browser's convention. More information about this attribute at [this WebAIM article on keyboard accessibility](http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/accesskey).

Comment: By the way, curious what type of hotkeys you're planning on implementing? The old `accesskey`-style of hotkey seems to have faded somewhat - even bbc.co.uk, which used to support it, no longer does; though I note that Facebook does use it for navigation. Also, if you hit the `?` key when logged into Facebook, Gmail or Twitter you'll get a popup outlining their keyboard support.

Comment: I'm just using Alt 1-5 Q-T A-G Z-B to give accessibility shortcut-keys to navigate the site. It's working for windows across multiple browsers and will work on all standard keyboards. The only issue I have at the moment is Mac keyboards.